# Wordpress theme OneNote: Ajax Pagination show always the same page

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a big problem: in my site, the Wordpress pagination show always the same page: as you can see here, near the footer there's the ajaxed pagination, but shown always the first page!

Please help me, cause this big problem drives me crazy soon! -.-
The theme is OneNote from MyThemeShop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the arguments in Wp_Query

```
<?php 
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$pr_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'properties',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => ''); 

$the_query = new WP_Query($pr_args);
?>
```

> Change the `post_type`, in my case it was `properties`

Comment: This is my template code: http://pastebin.com/HZDPNwsZ

Where I doing the edit of Wp_Query function?